# AWS SSO - Account Acccess Pattern/Automation

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-sso

I have a new AWS management account with SSO set up. I am not clear on how I can give access to some "user" which will be used to run terraform. What I would like to do is create a role in each non-management account. Then in the management account create a group, with a policy that allows any user in that group to assume the role in any "non-mangement" account.

However, in the "non-management" account, I am not able to set the trust policy to allow a "group" to assume the role, it seems like only individual users are allowed. However, this means in the management account, whenever I add a user, I have to manually then come into each "non-management" account and update the trust policy to now allow this new user to assume the role as well. Obviously, this isn't ideal, and I'm sure theres a simpler way to automate this.

Or is this even the best approach to doing this ? I've also tried the hub and spoke approach with a single non-sso user in the management account. This works, but somehow seems like its not a clean approach.

Comment: Well, if we're talking about using AWS Organizations, then a role is created in each of the accounts added directly through the AWS Organizations (but not if you had created a standalone account). You also wouldn't add a user, rather a role, which would then trust IAM entities from the management account and the permissions policy would allow whatever terraform needs to create.

Comment: @MarkoE My current set up is that for terraform only, i have created a user in the management account using regular old IAM, and then a role in every other account. There is a trust policy between the two to allow the user to assume the role, and then I have specific limits on the role in each account as well. What I am wondering is if i even need a specific "terraform" user or not. I can just allow users created via SSO to get their own credentials and run terraform using that. Originally my question was, how can i create a group in identity center and add users to that which can execute tf.